# How to convert HTTP status code into text in Java?

Tags: java, http

How can I convert HTTP status code to its text representation, in Java? I mean are there any existing implementations of such a conversion. The best I've found so far is `java.ws.rs.core.Response.Status#fromStatusCode()`, which converts only a limited subset of all statuses.

Comment: Create your own map <Integer, String>. You can read it from an xml, for example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a conformant HTTP server MUST send a status code AND a status text.

Comment: Yes, I also think that my server has to send code and text, that's why I'm asking :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) has an (old-style) enum class which does this:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpStatus.html

You can call its`getStatusText` method with an enum instance as the argument to get the text representation of a status code.

Maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The "commons-httpclient" is end of life (last release 2007). The new library is org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore and the method to get the status text is EnglishReasonPhraseCatalog.INSTANCE.getReason(status, null);

Answer (score 10):

If you're happy to import Spring web, `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(int).name()` should do, if you don't mind underscores.

Comment: This returns the code number as string, not the text representation.

Comment: `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(response.statusCode()).getReasonPhrase()` will work

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Spring, or are okay with importing Spring Web, then this would do it:

First import it:

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
```

Then use it like:

```java
int statusCode = 502;
String message = HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode).getReasonPhrase();
```