# How can I get the description of ResponseCode of HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, http-response-codes

After calling the following code, `getResponseCode()` returns the response code returned by the remote HTTP server. This code has a short description. How can I get its description programmatically in Android?

```
URL myurl = new URL(url);
URLConnection connection = myurl.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
```

**UPDATE**

`httpConnection.getResponseMessage()` sometimes returns "not found" whereas responseCode is valid

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert HTTP status code into text in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179547/how-to-convert-http-status-code-into-text-in-java)

Comment: Regarding your Update: did it ever occur that the actual response message **is literally** "not found"? In other words: your reponse code is 404, because the resource was *not found*.

Comment: you are right. it was my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `getResponseMessage()`, it will a string message you may interesting.

Comment: I tested it. it does not return its description

Comment: what kind of description do you want? `HTTP/1.0 200 OK HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found. Extracts the Strings "OK" and "Not Found" respectively. Returns null if none could be discerned from the responses (the result was not valid HTTP).`

Comment: for example `public static final int HTTP_OK :

OK 
` or `public static final int HTTP_PROXY_AUTH :
Proxy authentication required` or `public static final int HTTP_VERSION : Version not supported`

Comment: 200 means `HTTP_OK` you can get it from `getResponseCode()`. there are some static variable in HttpURLConnection, have a look at api http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: is that all you code? you should sent out a get or post methods to that url, then call getCode or getMessage() to check whether you request is handled properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
httpConnection.getResponseMessage()
```

Comment: I tested it. it does not return its description

Answer (score 2):

The docs say:

> Gets the HTTP response message, if any, returned along with the response code from a server. >From responses like: 
>   HTTP/1.0 200 OK
>   HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 
>   Extracts the Strings "OK" and "Not Found" respectively. Returns null if none could be >discerned from the responses (the result was not valid HTTP).

Maybe there isn't a message from your server?
You can also write your own method which will return descriptions for codes.
e.g

```
    public static String getMessage(int code) {
        switch(code) {
            case 200: return "OK";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you're more than welcome to check the [HTTP/1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) that holds exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: How can I get its description programmatically?

Comment: why would you need that?! the whole point of the protocol is to refer to messages as codes